# Directional derivative of $T(x,y,z)=yz+zx+xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If the temperature at a point $(x,y,z)$ of a solid ball of radius 3 centred at $(0,0,0)$ is given by $T(x,y,z)=yz+zx+xy$ find the direction in which $T$ is increasing most rapidly at $(1,1,2)$.

My approach:
First by taking the derivative of $T$

$T'(x,y,z)=(z+y)i+(z+x)j+(y+x)k$

The vector $(1,1,2)$ can be normalised as $\frac{(1,1,2)}{\sqrt{6}}$

However, I'm unsure with what to do with the statement "of a solid ball of radius 3 centred at $(0,0,0)$"?

There's also a hint to this: $\frac{\partial T}{\partial \mathbf{u}}=\mathbf{u}\cdot (3,3,2)$ But I'm unsure on how to piece this together, do I multiply the vector of temperature by (3,3,2)? then what's next?

Comment: $T$ increases the most in the direction of the gradient of $T$ at the point $(1,1,2)$. Also your derivative of $T$ is not correct.

Comment: Likely no one cares, but calling that $T'$ is bothering me.  Gradients and derivatives are completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T'(x,y,z)=(z+y) \hat i + (z+x) \hat j+(y+x) \hat k$

So gradient vector at $(1, 1, 2)$ is,

$T' (1, 1, 2) = 3 \hat i + 3 \hat j + 2 \hat k$

We know the maximum rate of increase is in the direction of the gradient vector so normalizing it, the direction in which the temperature increases the most at point $(1, 1, 2)$ is $ \displaystyle  \frac{1}{\sqrt{22}} \ (3, 3, 2)$ and the maximum rate of increase is $\sqrt{22}$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I understand how my reasoning went wrong by looking at this. I think the wording  of the question threw me off!